# Spark AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Spark on Hortonworks Data Platform 2.2, I get the following error...any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext

if 'sc' not in globals():
    #sc = SparkContext('local[4]', 'pyspark','map')
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonKMeans")

nums = sc.map([23,232,1,232,43,43])
squared = nums.map(lambda x: x*x).collect()
for num in squared:
    print num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
nums = sc.map([23,232,1,232,43,43])
```

try

```
nums = sc.parallelize([23,232,1,232,43,43])
```

That tells Spark to distribute the sequence over the cluster and create an RDD out of it. You can then call map with a lambda function over the RDD, as you do in the next line.